# Backup GAE Data/Files from Blob Store to Google Cloud Storage / other space

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, blobstore

In my application on Google App Engine, I have files/documents uploaded to Blob Store. The size of Blob Store has grown to more than 100 GB.

I am in search of a mechanism by which I can backup my blob store data, may be to some other server location or Google Cloud Storage or some other safe place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a simple tool that you can use to backup your Blobstore data.  There are at least a few approaches that you could take to write your own tool:

1. Use cron.xml and a servlet (or some similar scheduling) to copy batches of your entity blobs to Google Cloud Storage and then download from there (see below for tools).
2. Use remote-API or provide some other API (REST etc) where a remote tool you make can query your entities and then over a serving url (that you probably already have) download the Blobs to your local machine.

Those approaches are not very friendly and there are however tools such as [GSUtil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) that would be helpful if you migrated your data to Google Cloud Storage (GCS).  I've seen a few people migrate their data now that upload and serving with GCS is supported with the Blobstore API.

It's important to also note that the Files API for Blobstore is now deprecated (since 1.8.1?) and that there is a new preferred way through the [App Engine GCS client](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/).

Additionally if you check [Posts about 1.8.1 Pre-release SDKs Available.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/zzpFI5PQbLI) you'll see that there is some indication from Google that blobs might be auto-migrated over to Cloud Storage (free of charge) before the end of the year (presumably close to when Blobstore will be deprecated).  Depending on the urgency of your needs it may be feasible to just wait.

Comment: I am planning to wait till this change happens. I may plan to write a Bulk Download script so that I can download the content on a local system (Not thought about, how can it be implemented). Can you recommend if this can be done?

Comment: @aadhaar - glad it was helpful.  I've added a couple of ideas above but I guess it depends on your situation as to what makes the most sense.  Personally I'd probably just "bite the bullet" and migrate my blobs to GCS.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Backup/Restore functionality of GAE Admin console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin).

Comment: I understand data in the datastore can be backed up to Blob Store or Google Cloud storage, but what about data in Blobstore. Need to backup the files/documents uploaded in Blobstore.

Comment: That is for Datastore, not Blobstore